# Does the Resistance know that Supreme Leader Snoke exists?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, snoke

In *Star Wars: The Force Awakens*,

> do the Resistance and Rey, Leia, etc. (all characters considered to be part of the *good side*) know that Supreme Leader Snoke exists and is the mastermind behind the First Order and Kylo Ren? Or is Snoke unknown to them and operating in shadow?

Comment: Doesn’t Han mention Snoke when he confronts Kylo Ren?

Comment: He does - something to the effect of "Snoke is just using you for your power"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Yes.

Leia (aka **Resistance leader General Organa**) tells Han that Snoke was the one who corrupted their son Ben

> into becoming Kylo Ren

From Alan Dean Foster novelization:

First we have Maz discussing Snoke with Han:

> “I need you to get this droid to the Resistance…,” Han said.
> “Me?” Maz said archly.
> “…and the loan sounds good too.”
> “I see you’re in trouble,” Maz said. “I’ll help you find passage—avoid **Snoke’s hunter squads** — but this journey to the Resistance isn’t mine to take, and you know it.”

And then Leia's chat with him

> “We both did,” Leia admitted.
> He met her eyes steadily. “We’ve lost our son, forever.”
> Leia bit her lower lip, refusing to concede. “**No. It was Snoke**".

She even admits she **knew this for a long time** - so this knowledge isn't merely from the year *The Force Awakening* is in:

> Han drew back slightly. “Snoke?”
> She nodded. “He knew our child would be strong with the Force. That he was born with equal potential for good or evil.”
> **“You knew this from the beginning? Why didn’t you tell me?”
>
> She sighed. “Many reasons**.

Comment: +1 That Alan Dean Foster novelization is paying off for you, isn't it? :P

Comment: @AndresF. - I would say it's paying off for people reading these answers and gleaning useful info even more, eh?

Comment: Yes, that too :)

Comment: The novelization is great, so much cannon answers from them.

Answer (score 18):

## Yes

General Leia Organa, **leader of the Resistance**, knows about Snoke. Since Han, Leia, and Luke<sup>1</sup> all know about Snoke, it makes sense that **the Resistance would also know about him.**

- Han and Leia talk about Snoke, mentioning him by name.

  > HAN: We’ve lost our son, forever.
  >
  > LEIA: No. It was **Snoke**.
- Later Han says something along the lines of

  > HAN: **Snoke** is just using you for your power, and then he'll discard you.
- Han and Leia were together when their son

  > was persuaded to betray Luke and follow the Dark Side **by Snoke**.

---

<sub>[1] - Luke's own student was seduced by Snoke to join the Dark Side. If Ben's *parents* know about that, I'm sure Luke, Ben's *trainer*, would too.</sub>

Comment: Beat you by 2 minutes :))) Good answer though!

Comment: =(::::: (btw, that's a crying face, in case you couldn't tell) I take took long with the formatting; I should just post and then edit like you do, lol.

Comment: sorry, can't blame the formatting. My first draft had the spoiler tags already :) I just added novelization quotes after

Comment: You don't show any evidence that Luke knows.

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard I edited to add some clarification.

Comment: Fair enough I suppose.  But hypothetically Han and Leia could have learned Snoke's identity after Luke had already left.